# Rails router fallback on not defined resource in namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

what i am struggle with is how to define a fallback for not defined routes in a namespace.

Example:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 
 namespace :v1 do
   resources :foo
   resources :bar
 end

 namespace :v2 do
   resources: :foo
 end

end
```

Now as `bar` is not defined in `v2` a request to /v2/bar should be handled by /v1/bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick, if i understood You correctly.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

 namespace :v2 do
   resources :foo
 end

 scope '(/:api_version)', api_version: /v(1|2)/, module: :v1 do
   resources :foo
   resources :bar
 end
end
```

order matters.